# Bad Gateway(502.3) for a single view page and other pages are working fine in same localhost Asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

It was working fine.
but now bad gate way error only for Home page and still other pages are working fine. Db connection working fine. 
it was happening when i create home view page. i cannot figure out what is happened. 
what should i do for it .
VS2017 & SQL Server 2014. 
[image: This error for only my home page.]

[image: Other pages work fine in same localhost]

Comment: Share us the code for `/Home/Home/Index`. Try enabling `stdoutLogEnabled`, is there any detail error message?

Comment: Thank you very much considering this. I couldn't find any answer, therefore delete Home controller and their view. start to code everything.